# How to defer lifetime checking to runtime

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to pass a non-static closure into tokio. Obviously this doesn't work. Is there a way to make sure the lifetimes are appropriate at runtime? Here's what I tried:

## Attempt with `Arc`

In order to not pass the closure directly into tokio, I put it into the struct that manages our timers:

```rust
type Delays<'l, K: Eq + Hash + Debug + Copy + Send> = HashMap<K, Box<dyn FnOnce() + 'l + Send>>;

pub struct Timers<'l, K: Eq + Hash + Debug + Clone + Send> {
    delays: Arc<Mutex<Delays<'l, K>>>,
}
```

The `impl` for that struct lets us easily add and remove timers. My plan was to somehow pass a static closure into tokio, by only moving a `Weak` reference
to the mutexed hashmap:

```rust
// remember handler function
        delays.insert(key.clone(), Box::new(func));

        // create a weak reference to the delay map to pass into the closure
        let weak_handlers = Arc::downgrade(&self.delays);

        // task that runs after a delay
        let task = Delay::new(Instant::now() + delay)
            .map_err(|e| warn!("Tokio timer error: {}", e)) // Map the error type to ()
            .and_then(move |_| {
                // get the handler from the table, of which we have only a weak ref.
                let handler = Weak::upgrade(&weak_handlers)
                    .ok_or(())? // If the Arc dropped, return an error and thus aborting the future
                    .lock()
                    .remove(&key)
                    .ok_or(())?; // If the handler isn't there anymore, we can abort aswell.

                // call the handler
                handler();

                Ok(())
            });
```

So with the `Weak` we make sure that we abort, if the hash table was dropped.

It's important to know that the lifetime `'l` is the same as that of the `Timers` struct, but how can I tell the compiler? Also, I think the real problem is that `Weak<T>: 'static` is not satisfied.

## Writing it myself using `unsafe`

I tried building something similar to [Sc](https://github.com/dureuill/sc) to achieve this. First, is Sc going to work here? I read the code and understand it. I can't see any obvious problems - though it was kind of hard to come to the conclusion that the `map` method is actually safe, because the reference will definitely be dropped at the end of the `map` and not stored somewhere.

So I tried to adapt Sc for my needs. This is only a rough outline and I know there are some issues with this, but I believe something like this should be possible:

- Have a `struct Doa<T>` that will own `T`
- `Doa::ref(&self) -> DoaRef<T>` will produce a opaque object that internally contain a `*const u8` to the owned object.
- - `DoaRef` doesn't contain references with non-static lifetimes and thus can be passed to tokio.
- Have `impl<T> Drop for Doa<T>` that sets that `*const u8` to `null`
- So the `DoaRef` can now check if the value still exists and get a reference to it.

I also tried to make sure that the lifetime of `&self` in `ref` must be longer than the lifetimes of references in `T`, to ensure this works only if `Doa` really lives longer than the object the pointer points to.

```
struct Doa<'t, T: 'l> { ... }
pub fn ref(&'s self) -> DoaRef<T> where 't: 'a
```

But then `T` is lifetime-contrained and since `DoaRef` is parameterized over it `DoaRef: 'static` doesn't hold anymore.

Or is there some crate, or maybe even something in `std` that can do this?